# Pointer arithmetic ignored by the compiler

Tags: c++

I'm compiling the following with -O0 (recent gcc/clang) and they both give me a answer I don't expect.

```
#include <iostream>

struct xy{
    int x,y;
};


int main()
{
  xy a{1,2};

  int x{1};
  int y{2};

  int *ptr1=&a.x;
  int *ptr2=&x;

  ptr1++;    // I now point to a.y!
  (*ptr1)++; // I now incremented a.y to 3

  ptr2++;    // I now point to y!
  (*ptr2)++; // I now incremented y to 3

  std::cout << "a.y=" << a.y << " ptr1=" << *ptr1 << '\n'; 
  std::cout << "y=  " << y << " ptr2=" << *ptr2 << '\n'; 
}
```

Output:

```
a.y=3 ptr1=3
y=  2 ptr2=2
```

So this access with pointers to non-class variables is being optimized-out by the compiler.

I also tried to mark the int and int* as volatile, but it didn't make any difference.

What part of the standard am I missing / why is the compiler allowed to do this?

Coliru snippet at: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed0757a6621c37a9

Comment: You can't use pointer arithmetic like that on things that aren't elements of an array. It is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @juanchopanza You can but there is only so much you can do with that pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver I said you can't use it *like that* :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah yes.  Missed that.  :-)

Comment: [It works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b77dc1006dfcd6f2) as you would expect if you switch `x` and `y`, as the stack grows downwards. But you can't rely on this, as it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KarstenKoop you actually answer another part of the question: It was not actually a optimization problem but a bug in my code since I was not considering the sequence in memory to be reversed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case dealing with class members the part you are ignoring is the compiler is allowed to add any amount of padding in between members of a object and at the end of the object.  Because of this increment a pointer to one member does not have to give you the next member.

The second part of the standard you are missing is it is illegal to access memory though a pointer to what it doesn't point to.  Even though `y` might be there in memory the pointer is not allowed to access it.  It is allowed to access `x` and it is allowed to compare to see if it one past `x` but it cannot dereference that one past `x` address.

Comment: Being a class with only ints, isn't it guaranteed to be POD and so in this case have exactly the same memory structure as int a[2]? I don't believe the compiler is allowed to pad it, even considering alignment requirements.

Comment: @nunojpg [class.mem] states *If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address of its first non-static data member. Otherwise, its address is the same as the address of its first base class subobject (if any). [ Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. —end note ]* so there can be padding.

Answer (score 3):

Pointer arithmetic is *only* valid in arrays. You cannot reach `y` by incementing a pointer to `x`. The behaviour of your program is *undefined*. Your statement

`ptr1++;    // I now point to a.y!`

is simply wrong. Remember that a compiler is allowed to insert an arbitrary amount of *padding* between the elements in your `struct`.

In more detail, you can set a pointer to one past the address of a scalar, but you are not allowed to *dereference* it.